# Django: Authentication credentials not povided error as access and refresh tokens are set as HttpOnly cookies without Authorization header

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-headers, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, cookie-httponly

I have set `SimpleJWT` `access` and `refresh` tokens as HttpOnly cookies. Therefore, I thought that I don't need to use the 'Authorization' header anymore, so I removed it. Now, when I'm making requests it's showing:

```
{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Here, I think I need to set the `Authorization` header to `access` token in the view. So far I have written this code but it is not working. I want it to set the `Authorization` header to the request and proceed:

```
def list(self, request):
    access = request.COOKIES.get('access')
    request.META['Authorization'] = f"Bearer {access}"
    print(request.META.get('Authorization'))
    serializer = self.serializer_class(instance = self.request.user) 
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

How do I send the `Authorization` header with the request if it's not coming from the client?

Answer (score 1):

**Define your custom JWT authentication view like this:**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from django.conf import settings


class CustomAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    
    def authenticate(self, request):
        header = self.get_header(request)
        
        if header is None:
            raw_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE']) or None
        else:
            raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)
        if raw_token is None:
            return None

        validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)

        return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
```

Here give path of custom JWT Token:

**settings.py:**

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
........
'AUTH_COOKIE': 'access_token',
}
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'authentication.authenticate.CustomAuthentication',
        ),
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, I followed this repository with middleware approach and it worked: https://github.com/HarryAustin/tweeter-DrfTest-httonlycookie/blob/main/Django_Rest_Framework/middleware.py

Comment: Yes but my method work on both.Client can forcely send `JWT` token(useful in mobile app)  or DRF automatically catch the token through `httponly` cookie.